# VMware vCloud Air Security

Tags: security, vmware, virtualization, user-management, vsphere

How do I make my vCloud Air account secure? It was really easy for me to handle this when I was on vSphere but not sure how to do this for my organization on the public cloud of VMware. I have some 30 employees who would need access to my vCloud Air account.

Comment: Any code you have tried?

Comment: @Irshad - No. I am just getting a flavor of the public cloud. I had my infra on the private till now, that's vSphere. We planning to migrate soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware vCloud Air has a feature where you can a user with specific permission. They have 4 different types of access from the Admin level to Read-only access. I am sure you wouldn't want all 30 emp to have same kind of access, so this feature will help you out. There are several other actions you can perform on existing users like Enable/Disable user.

I went through an article on VMware vCloud Air user management. Good part is it includes steps. Have you seen, http://goo.gl/Tjb4FP ?

Comment: Thanks that helped! Got overall idea.